# Getting Tap even of user control in viewmodel

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8

In my application i am using a content control to display my user control

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding LayoutControl}" Grid.Row="0" Height="700" Width="450"/>
```

In here the binding content is a user control with the following elements.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#6C7172">
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="7">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath0}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ImageTap}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

In the above code what i am tried to implement is, while tapping on the image i need to fire the corresponding event in my view model, But through this code the tap event is not firing. But when i apply the interactivity to content control the click is working. I cannot simply add tap event to content control because some other cases i need to handle tap events of more than two Image controls . Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a fixed height and width to you image control and then try. It will work. If there is no image in the container means, the mouse will not get a position for tapping. Try this and if you still face the same issue give me a feedback.